# Group messaging on Samsung J2

Tags: samsung, sms, instant-messaging

How do you do group messaging on a Samsung J2? I can send out a group message but when people reply, it comes in as individual texts, not in a group conversation. I cannot find the option to turn on group conversation.

Answer (score 1):

SMS is one-to-one; your phone is texting each person in the group individually, and the app is just simplifying this for you.  There is no information transmitted to them about the group or about past conversations, nor is there any information transmitted in their replies about what they are replying to.  As such it is impossible for your phone to tell that their replies should be grouped together rather than kept separate.

Some messaging apps (like Google's [Messages](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging)) support group messaging over MMS, which may incur additional expenses.

Otherwise, you'll have to get everyone to sign up for some other service like WhatsApp or Line and create a group within that.